# Android Open Application

Tags: android

On android ,have any listener whenever we open any new application on device ?
or any way to know user open new application or we print into log?

Answer (score 0):

Best match would be BroadcastReceiver listening to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED